# Part of my PlayerExpChangeEvent is being overridden by vanilla

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I'm making a spigot plugin (version 1.8.8) that has an function that I know works because it fires flawlessly through my command. However, when I call it at the end of a PlayerExpChangeEvent, it seems like vanilla leveling overrides the bar, making it go up way more that it is supposed to. Running the command/function after this happens makes the bar go back to how it is supposed to be. **I've tried setting my event's priority to highest** (and when that didn't work, to lowest) but no matter what my function appears to be completely ignored when called inside the event.

Here is some code:

```
@EventHandler(priority=EventPriority.HIGHEST)
  public void onXpGain(PlayerExpChangeEvent event)
  {
// Load custom levels from config
    ArrayList<String> levelList = new ArrayList<String>(plugin.getConfig().getStringList("levels"));
    if (!((String)levelList.get(0)).equals("none"))
    {
      Player player = event.getPlayer();
      Iterator<String> var4 = levelList.iterator();
      while (var4.hasNext())
      {
        String s = (String)var4.next();
        String[] splits = s.split(" ");
        int levelCompare = Integer.parseInt(splits[0]);
        int playerLvl = player.getLevel();

        // Detect if on correct tier, else continue iteration
        if (playerLvl == levelCompare - 1)
        {
          // Calculate the player's new XP amount
          int totalXp = player.getTotalExperience() + event.getAmount();
          player.setTotalExperience(totalXp);
          updateBar(event.getPlayer()); // <-- THIS IS THE FUNCTION
          return;
      }
    }
      // At max level
      player.setTotalExperience(player.getTotalExperience() + event.getAmount());
      player.setLevel(getHighestLevel(levelList));
      player.setExp(1.0f);
   }
  }
```

And here is the function itself. Keep in mind that it works fine when called through a command and not an event. It's purpose is to use the player's total XP to set the level and bar. Neither set correctly in the event; it instead embraces vanilla leveling.

```
public static void updateBar(Player player) {

    ArrayList<String> levelList = new ArrayList<String>(plugin.getConfig().getStringList("levels"));
    int totalXp = player.getTotalExperience();

        player.setLevel(getHighestLevelForXp(totalXp, levelList));

        if (player.getLevel() < getHighestLevel(levelList)) {

            int lvlDiff = getTotalXpToLevel(player.getLevel() + 1,levelList) - getTotalXpToLevel(player.getLevel(),levelList);
            int xpDiff = totalXp - getTotalXpToLevel(player.getLevel(),levelList);

            player.setExp((float)xpDiff/lvlDiff);
        } else {
            player.setLevel(getHighestLevel(levelList));
            player.setExp(0.0f);
        }
    return;
  }
```

The command where the function works correctly is a bare-bones call to the function and doesn't need a mention here. Does anyone know how to get my event to override vanilla xp gain? The update works through the command, just not natural xp gain. It is already confirmed that the event DOES fire, as the rest of the event changes the internal xp amount, but the visual effects are overridden by vanilla. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You can cancel the event so that a change doesn't happen before you do the rest, maybe that's enough

Comment: @Kerooker Cancel the event? That sounds like that's what I need but what is that? (Maybe give it in an answer so I can accept your answer)

Comment: @Kerooker The PlayerExpChangeEvent doesn't have a .setcancelled() method.

Comment: What happens if you set the priority to lowest?  If that makes it run last, after the default function, then it should display correctly (this is if the events are ran from highest to lowest priority)

Comment: Try maybe to set the experience given in the event?

Comment: `event.setAmount(0)` Will set to 0 the experience gained through the event according to the [javadocs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerExpChangeEvent.html)

Comment: Thanks @Kerooker. Figured that out last night :)

Comment: Was this the solution? If it was, I'll bring it to an answer for future users

Comment: Yes. Please put an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only setting the Player's EXP won't be enough for your desired behaviour. The Vanilla behaviour **will still complete**, as you're not changing how the event will add EXP to the player.

Currently, your event is working like this:

[image: Flow of an Experience event. Starting at a Player getting EXP, which leads to a PlayerExpGainEvent being fired. When the event completes, the EXP is added to the player, not mattering if there's an Interception.]

And `PlayerExpGainEvent` isn't cancellable, so you cannot undo it's addition of EXP.

What you can do instead is to **set the EXP the event will add to 0**, therefore not changing the player's EXP after your interception.

```
event.setAmount(0);    //Cancelling the EXP addition
```

I would recommend to set your event to a high priority, so that other events that depend on Experience gain won't trigger when you set the amount gained to 0.